# display an image in a web page using javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to automate my website by setting predetermined monthly featured videos. 
I have JavaScript files already saved w/ the annual data for that particular year - e.g. choose_2017_video.js as well as 2018 & 2019 files. Each image URL text and description text I set in arrays but I can't seem to get them to display. Each array element corresponds to a month [0-11].
The getMonth() method will be the way of retrieving the data.

Somehow, I need to import the song info. into the HTML roughly like this:

```
<h2 align="center">Video of the month: javascript:song_info[mnth];</h2>
```

I also need to be able to import the corresponding image path which is saved in a parallel array (of filenames).

```
var song_info[12], img_URL[12], mnth = today().getMonth();
song_info[7] = "Newsboys - God's Not Dead"; // example data
img_URL[7] = "Newsboys-Gods_Not_Dead_video.JPG";
```

This site won't let me correctly describe how I'll display the img code using the img_URL element.

Can someone give me examples of how I can import the song information into the h2 code example and img src code?

Comment: you can re-phrase your question to make it clear?

Comment: can you show how you import your JavaScript (`choose_2017_video.js`) data and the JavaScript content?

Comment: `song_info[12]` and `img_URL[12]` aren't valid variable declarations. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: Why do you use this format for your data, is it a constraint or you chose it? If it's your choice, can you concidere using Json?

Answer (score 0):

This might be done a lot easier in an ASP script since I'm more familiar w/ BASIC. JS wasn't even conceived until after I had entered the workforce after a couple yrs. in college.

My intent is to declare new arrays and a pointer variable. The pointer is supposed to determine the month from the current date. One array holds the description of the song while the other holds the filename of the screenshot to be used to launch the YouTube URL in a different browser tab. If I wanted to embed the video, I would just use HTML5 code. It is called by a script src="JSfilename" from an HTML file.

Here is one of the JS files:

```
var song_info[12], img_URL[12], mnth = today().getMonth();
song_info[0] = "Sidewalk Prophets - Help Me Find It"; 
song_info[1] = "TobyMac with Kirk Franklin & Mandisa - Lose Your Soul";  
song_info[2] = "MercyMe - Dear Younger Me"; 
song_info[3] = "Kari Jobe - I Am Not Alone"; 
song_info[4] = "Danny Gokey - Tell Your Heart to Beat Again"; 
song_info[5] = "Hawk Nelson - Drops In the Ocean"; 
song_info[6] = "Plumb - Exhale"; 
song_info[7] = "Newsboys - God's Not Dead"; 
song_info[8] = "Francesca Battistelli - Holy Spirit"; 
song_info[9] = "Brandon Heath - Give Me Your Eyes"; 
song_info[10] = "Matthew West - Strong Enough"; 
song_info[11] = "Jordan Feliz - The River"; 
img_URL[0] = "Sidewalk_Prophets-Help_Me_Find_It_video.png";
img_URL[1] = "TobyMac-LoseMySoul_video.png";
img_URL[2] = "MercyMe-DearYoungerMe_video.png";
img_URL[3] = "KariJobe-IAmNotAlone_video.png";
img_URL[4] = "DannyGokey-TellYourHeartToBeatAgain_video3.PNG";
img_URL[5] = "HawkNelson-DropsInTheOcean_video.PNG";
img_URL[6] = "Plumb-Exhale_video.PNG";
img_URL[7] = "Newsboys-Gods_Not_Dead_video.JPG";
img_URL[8] = "FrancescaBattistelli-HolySpirit_video.JPG";
img_URL[9] = "BrandonHeath-GiveMeYourEyes_video.JPG";
img_URL[10] = "Matthew_West-StrongEnough_video.JPG";
img_URL[11] = "JordanFeliz-TheRiver_video.PNG";
```

Comment: That fixed it. I probably accidentally imposed C or C++ verbiage to the JS. Thanks! It's going to take mew a while to figure out JS. When I was being taught programming, JS didn't exist yet, BASIC & Pascal are essentially dead languages although BASIC morphed into VB whic in turn became ASP > ASP.NET. I wish Java (OOP) would have been my starting point instead of BASIC. I'd be set.

Comment: well, that fixed the heading; I need to tweak the image potion now

Comment: I was able to set the URL, but had to add the following to the HTML page to have it redirect when clicking the image link.
 <a href="javascript:window.location.replace(video_link);" id="YouTube_link"><img src="#" alt="YouTube link" id="video_preview" /></a>
 <script src="../JS/2017_VOM_MM.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

So to be clear, you want something like

```
<h2 align="center">Video of the month: {your_random_video_name_from_your_JSFile}</h2>
```

So why not just doing this :

```
<h2 align="center" id="video_name">Video of the month:</h2>
  <img src="#" alt="" id="video_preview"/>
  <script>
    var today = new Date();
    var song_info = new Array, img_URL = new Array, mnth = today.getMonth();
    song_info[9] = "CHVRCHES - Leave A Trace"; // example data
    img_URL[9] = "http://diymag.com/media/img/Artists/C/Chvrches/October-cover/_1500x1000_crop_center-center_75/chvrches-mike-massaro-diy-2015-05.jpg";
    song_info[10] = "Newsboys - God's Not Dead"; // example data
    img_URL[10] = "Newsboys-Gods_Not_Dead_video.JPG";
    document.getElementById("video_name").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',song_info[mnth]);
    var image = document.getElementById("video_preview");
    image.src = img_URL[mnth];
  </script>
```

Example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lerzats/e7h1bt17/)